# Windows 2003 Server And Wordpress

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis-6, wordpress

Hy!

I own a VPS hosting on a Windows 2003 Server.I am planning on moving the hosting service of a domain that I own "thecitybear.com" on to this server. The site uses a wordpress platform. I have installed MySql 5.1 and PHP 5.2.9. What's the next Step?Installing IIS 6.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed these instructions and had pretty good luck:

http://blogbuildingu.com/wordpress/install-wordpress-wemp

The downside, though, was that WordPress's automatic upgrades, plugin installations and theme installations never seemed to work right.  The latest versions (2.7 and 2.8) of WordPress can do this stuff over FTP, but you'll need to set up an FTP server too.

Another caveat is the caching plugins, which seemed to be very hit-or-miss (mostly miss) with Windows hosting.  If you rely on WP Super Cache to handle load, then really test it well with several different browsers.  My IE users complained that the site was sending them zip files when they clicked on links, and that the gzip compression was just not easy to configure correctly.  It seemed to work okay without WP Super Cache, but as soon as I got caching involved, everything went downhill.

I ended up switching back to a Linux host, for what it's worth.

Comment: Okay,got it.How do i point the domain "thecitybear" to my server?

Comment: You need to change the DNS records.  Your DNS records are being hosted by ns1.ipvhost.ro - contact them and work with them to set up the IP address of your new Windows hosted server.

Answer (score 2):

By *far* the easiest way to setup Wordpress (or Drupal, or DotNetNuke) is to use the free Web Platforms Installer (http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx).  It handles the downloading, prerequisites, and installation.

From the download description:

*The Microsoft Web Platform Installer
2.0 (Web PI) is a free tool that makes it simple to download, install and keep up-to-date with the latest components of the Microsoft Web Platform, including Internet Information Services (IIS), SQL Server Express, .NET Framework and Visual Web Developer. In addition, install popular open source ASP.NET and PHP web apps with the Web PI.*

Answer (score 0):

Keyboard face has a great article on permalinks in IIS/WordPress:

http://www.keyboardface.com/archives/2007/09/07/update-for-wordpress-permalinks-on-iis/

I've been running WordPress on Server2003/IIS6 for over 18 months now, with no issues - having moved from a Linux(CentOS)/Apache host to a dedicated Windows box.

Comment: I have succeded in installing XAMPP and getting the MYSQL PHP PHPMyAdmin working.Also imported the dababase succesfully.What DNS Manager to use ?how do i point the .com domain to my server?

Comment: If you've got a static IP on your Server, then find out who currently hosts the DNS for your domain and get them to point the A-Record to your new IP address. As long as you've got port 80 open, then you'll be able to view the site within 48 hours.